# Vectorize operation on dataframe where I need to subset another dataframe (pearson correlation)

Tags: python, pandas, subset, vectorization, pearson-correlation

What's the best way to do an operation on a dataframe that, for every row, I need to do a selection on another dataframe?

For example:

My first dataframe has the similarity between every to pairs of items. For starters, I'll assume every similarity as zero and calculate the correct similarity later.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.spatial import distance

 

items = [1,2,3,4]
item_item_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([items, items], names = ['from_item', 'to_item'])
item_item_df = pd.DataFrame({'similarity': np.zeros(len(item_item_idx))}, 
                            index = item_item_idx
                            )
```

My next dataframe has the rating every user gave for every item. For sake of simplification, let's assume  every user rated every item and generate random ratings between 1 and 5.

```
users = [1,2,3,4,5]

ratings_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([items, users], names = ['item', 'user'])
rating_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'rating': np.random.randint(low = 1, high =  6, size = len(users)*len(items))},
    columns = ['rating'],
    index = ratings_idx
    )
```

Now that I have the ratings, I want to update the cosine similarity between the items. What I need to do is, for every row in `item_item_df`, select to from `rating_df` the vector of ratings for each item, and calculate the cosine distance between those two.

I want to know the least dumb way to do this. Here's what I tried so far:

==== FIRST TRY - Iterating over rows

```
def similarity(ii, iu):
    
    for index, row in ii.iterrows():
        
        v = iu.loc[index[0]]
        u = iu.loc[index[1]]
        
        row['similarity'] = distance.cosine(v, u)
    
    return(ii)


import time

start_time = time.time()
item_item_df = similarity(item_item_df, rating_df)
print('Time: {:f}s'.format(time.time() - start_time))
```

Took me 0.01002s to run this. In problem with 10k items, I estimate it would take in th ballpark of 20 hours to run. Not good.

The thing is, I'm iterating over rows, my hope is that I can vectorize this to make it faster. I played around with df.apply() and df.map(). This is the best I did so far:

==== SECOND TRY - index.map()

```
def similarity_map(idx):
    
    v = rating_df.loc[idx[0]]
    u = rating_df.loc[idx[1]]
    
    return distance.cosine(v, u)

start_time = time.time()
item_item_df['similarity'] = item_item_df.index.map(similarity_map)
print('Time: {:f}s'.format(time.time() - start_time))
```

Took me 0.034961s to execute. Slower than just iterating over rows.

So this was a naive attempt to vectorize. Is it even possible to do? What other options I have to improve the runtime?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: The **second** answer to this question might be helpful: [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas).

Answer (score 0):

For your given example I'd just pivot it into an array and move on with my life.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

rating_df = rating_df.reset_index().pivot(index='item', columns='user')
cs_df = pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(rating_df),
                     index=rating_df.index, columns=rating_df.index)

>>> cs_df
item         1         2         3         4
item                                        
1     1.000000  0.877346  0.660529  0.837611
2     0.877346  1.000000  0.608781  0.852029
3     0.660529  0.608781  1.000000  0.758098
4     0.837611  0.852029  0.758098  1.000000
```

This would be more difficult with a giant, highly-sparse array. Sklearn cosine_similarity takes sparse arrays though so as long as your number of items is reasonable (since the output matrix will be dense) this should be solvable.

Comment: Yep. This works. Fast.

My specific problem is pretty much solved. Thank you.

Comment: Just to reiterate, I ran this in a sample of the real-world problem I'm working on, with 4k users and 14k items.

I was afraid I'd take 20 hours to do this. Your suggestion did it in 50 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing but different. Work with numpy arrays. Fine for small arrays but with 10k rows you'll have some large arrays.

```
import numpy as np
data = rating_df.unstack().values     # shape (4,5)
udotv = np.dot(data,data.T)           # shape (4,4)
mag_data = np.linalg.norm(data,axis=1)
mag = mag_data * mag_data[:,None]
cos_sim = 1 - (udotv / mag)
df['sim2'] = cos_sim.flatten()
```

4k users and 14k items pretty much blows up my poor computer. I'm going to have to look how `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity` handles that large data.